# Button will be triggered twice when using jquery live function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 columns in my application
On the 1st column it loads up during the website is loaded.

On the second column it will load up if a select box has been `"changed"`
The thing here is that this is how my code looks like:

```
jQuery(".pagination").live("click",function(event){
    var pId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    if( pId == "centerPagination")
        CenterColumnPagination();
    else if( pId == "searchPagination" )
        SearchColumnPagination();
});
```

The CenterPagination function their is called during the page load of my site. 
The SearchColumnPagination their is called when the select box is being triggered by `"changed"`

The reason why it is "click" their because on those 2 columns I have a class `.pagination` that has a button.

My problem here is that because of the `live` code, when I click on my 1st column, the button seems to be triggered twice, I noticed that one because when I checked the console of firebug, the ajax call has been called twice, and because of that, I get duplicate results.

And also on the second column, when I `changed` the select box(the pagination class would come out), then click on the button of the pagination class, it is also being triggered twice. Just same with the 1st column result.

What I want here is not to have those buttons being triggered twice, just like a normal click. Like when I click it, it should only call my ajax once.

Kindly guide me on this. Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to avoid using `live`. Instead of this I use `delegate`:

```
$('#column-1').delegate('.pagination', 'click', function () {
    CenterColumnPagination();    
});

$('#column-2').delegate('.pagination', 'click', function () {
    SearchColumnPagination();    
});
```

or, if you don't want to identify your columns you could do this like so:

```
jQuery('body').delegate(".pagination", "click", function(event) {
    var pId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    if( pId == "centerPagination")
        CenterColumnPagination();
    else if( pId == "searchPagination" )
        SearchColumnPagination();
});
```